# Is there an implementation of a trust on software on a host?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, hardware

What I'm after is a trust that is established between the hardware and the software intended to use that hardware.

This may require a certificate "burned in" to a specialized chip. The open SSL may need the same treatment.

On installation, the trust is formed, and unless you authenticate with a user key to the hardware key, you can't install anything.

Did I miss some reading out there where this is already done?

Comment: Are you talking about something like secure boot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is pretty much what "[truted computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Computing#Key_concepts)" is about: a tamper-resistant [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) chip contains an RSA key baked into it by the manufacturer.

You can achieve similar result using other type of tamper-resistant cryptographic storage ([HCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), smartcards, [DRM dongle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_protection_dongle), etc) where private keys are stored on specialized hardware and, theoretically, impossible to extract or duplicate.

Comment: dongles, those never really go away do they :)